# multiple selectpicker, disable option if selected option in another one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple select, and user can add more than select (make clone).
In every select includes option, and the same in all select,
on click add button make clone select div.

```
<select>
   <option value="en">English</option>
   <option value="ar">Arabic</option>
   <option value="tr">Turkey</option>
</select>
```

and more,...

I need to make that, when i select English from select one, Disabling the rest.

```js
var stdCountries = $("#countriesContainer").children(".countries").first().clone('.add');

        $(document).on('click', '.add',function() {
            append_countries();
        });

        function append_countries() {
            var objHtml = stdCountries.clone('.add');
            $("#countriesContainer").append(objHtml);
            $('.m_selectpicker').selectpicker();
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $(".m_selectpicker").selectpicker();
        $(document).on("click", ".remove", function(){
            if($('#countriesContainer .countries').length > 1)
            {
                $(this).closest(".countries").remove();
            }
            else
            {
                generate('info', 'error');
            }
        });
        
            $(document).on("change", ".m_selectpicker", function() {
            $(this).parents('.countries').find('.lang').attr('name', 'name' + '[' + this.value + ']');
            $(this).parents('.countries').find('.lang').attr('value', this.value);

        });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.5/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<form class="m-form m-form--fit m-form--label-align-right" id="m_form_1" method="post">
                <div class="m-portlet__body">
                    <div id="countriesContainer">
                        <div class="form-group m-form__group row countries">
                            <label class="col-form-label col-lg-2">Language</label>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <select class="form-control m-bootstrap-select m_selectpicker changeLanguage" data-live-search="true" name="language">
                                    <option value="en">Englsih</option>
                                    <option value="ar">Arabic</option>
                                    <option value="tr">Turkey</option>
                        
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <input type='text' class="form-control m-input lang" name="name[]" value=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-brand m-btn m-btn--custom add">
                                    add
                                </a>
                                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger m-btn m-btn--custom remove">
                                    remove
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   
                </div>
               
            </form>
```

if you any idea please to help me,
Thanks you
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="selectOne" class="form-control m-bootstrap-select m_selectpicker changeLanguage" data-live-search="true" name="language">
      <option value="en">Englsih</option>
      <option value="ar">Arabic</option>
      <option value="tr">Turkey</option>                   
</select>
```

Js

```
$(document).on("change", "#selectOne", function(){
  if($('#selectOne').val() == 'en'){
    $('select:not("#selectOne")').attr('disabled', true);​​​
  }else{
    $('select:not("#selectOne")').attr('disabled', false);​​​
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this select can multiple select i can clone div select.